# How can I stop a slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

When I click on some of the buttons I want the slideshow to stop working and let me see the img for 10s or 15s and then it goes back to work. I tried the setTimeout function but I think I didn't use it right. I checked some solutions here on stackoverflow for some problems that seemed like mine but nothing helped me.
Here is an executable version of my code:
    https://codepen.io/Amoocris/pen/MZXQYb?send-to-phone=5555555#0

Here is my code:

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlide();

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlide(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlide(n) {
  var i;
  slide = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlide");
  dotz = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
  for (i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
    slide[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slide.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dotz.length; i++) {
    dotz[i].className = dotz[i].className.replace("active", "");
  }
  slide[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  slide[slideIndex - 1].className += "active";
  setTimeout(showSlide, 3000);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 666.656px;
}

.mySlide {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.btns {
  text-align: center;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #bbb;
  margin: 0 2px;
}

.active,
.btn:hover {
  background-color: pink;
}

.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<body>


  <div class="slider-container">
    <div class="mySlide fade">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/70497/pexels-photo-70497.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="" class="img">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlide fade">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1639557/pexels-photo-1639557.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="" class="img">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlide fade">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1639565/pexels-photo-1639565.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=burger-close-up-delicious-1639565.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="" class="img">
    </div>
    <div class="btns">
      <span class="btn" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="btn" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="btn" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `var tId = setTimeout(showSlide, 3000);` now you can use `clearTimeout(tId)` to stop and re-issue `tId=setTimeout(showSlide, 3000);` when you want to start again

Comment: i have modified your pen. please check here https://codepen.io/raginrosevh/pen/yGEKmw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a variable to keep track of slideshow’s auto play. When a button is clicked, the auto play is cancelled until after a certain time period, say 5s.

Let’s set the variable to be `timer` and define it at the beginning of the slideshow section in the JS file:
    `var timer = null;`

Then in the `showSlide` function, in addition to calling `setTimeout` function like you are currently doing, you can assign the the return value of the function to `timer` so that you can cancel it whenever you need to:
    `timer = setTimeout(showSlide, 3000);`

Then in the button click function you’ll write, add the following code to temporarily cancel autoplay and set to resume it after 5 seconds:

```
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(showSlide, 5000);
```

Hope this helps.